# Angular 7 performance

Tags: angular, performance, http, animation, lazy-loading

I have an angular7 app with a list if items loaded in the main screen. data comes from the server via Httpcall. the problem is there are many animations in the list (i use ngLottie). i would like to display a loading palceholder for each item in the list until the item is completely loaded. there are many calls from my assets folder to get the json animations 
[image]

as you can see this call happens many times. the http call from the server comes pretty fast so i can't use it for my loading .

[image]

i also use `cdk-virtual-scroll`

```
<ul class="sources-list">
    <p *ngIf="filteredSources.length === 0" class="no-items">No sources {{filterValue | lowercase}}</p>
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 100%" itemSize="12">
      <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let source of filteredSources; trackBy: trackFn">
        <app-source-cube [source]="source"></app-source-cube>
      </ng-container>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </ul>
```

[image]

is there any way to display a placeholder until all the data is fully ready? and not from the server because the server returns is fast as i said before

all this area of the app is very slow and the screen is not responsive. is there anyway for me to make it more responsive for the user?

Comment: If the latency comes from displaying the data, I'm afraid you can't do much about it. Maybe reduce the amount of data displayed ? You could also totally rework your `source-cube` component, which is certainly the reason why your UI is lagging.

Comment: actually when after building with ng build --prod and serving on nginix this is pretty fast.